# Changing SATA cables, essentially changing computers without cutting off power to a drive

Tags: hard-drive, power-supply, sata

I was reading about SEDs, I came across a way of getting the data from an SED which is connected to an already running system, by plugging it into another computer without cutting the power supply to the hdd..

Is this possible, or are there complications which was not mentioned (or I am missing).

Comment: Why would you need to do it if you have the Authentication Key?

Comment: It is possible, but not as easy as it sounds, some Lenovo lapptops are not vulnerable to this, there is more than one method to achieve this, these methods are disclosed in a document from "blackhat Europe 2015", check it out it explains a lot better than what I could. Some seds even have a Master pwd and you can get it in the SED Manual (older models)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't hurt the drive.  SATA power and data connectors are physically designed to be hotplugged unlike Molex and classic EIDE/PATA.  Just take standard static electricity precautions.

I haven't done extensive research but IIRC using the hotplug capability requires chipset support, so you may run into the problem where that isn't supported on the destination system.  The worst that can happen is the destination system doesn't recognize the new drive.

Find out the chipset of the destination system and verify it supports SATA hotswapping or hotplugging for maximum chance of success.